# Problems using the operator "+=" in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, sum

Ok 
It's simple. I just want to add 1 to a number every time trought the use of `+=` operator!

So i go in prompt just like this:

```
C:\Users\fsilveira>SET teste=000007

C:\Users\fsilveira>ECHO %teste%
000007

C:\Users\fsilveira>SET /A teste+=1
8
C:\Users\fsilveira>
```

Wow nice. Seems to be working just fine.

From the behaviour of the last one, if I use the same operator again, it should just add one to eight right? So I guess I will have 9? But here is what's happening:

```
C:\Users\fsilveira>SET teste=000008

C:\Users\fsilveira>ECHO %teste%
000008

C:\Users\fsilveira>SET /A teste+=1
1
C:\Users\fsilveira>
```

What? 8 + 1 is 1 ? o_O

When it comes to the number 8 it does not work how it should (or how I believe it's suppose to)

I'm going insane over here.

Please some one could help me and explain to me what's happening?
I really dont know!

Regards,
Filipe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When prefixing with 0 it is intrepeated as an octal number. And 00008 is not a valid octal number. You can see the effect of this by the following:

```
C:\Users>SET teste=000020

C:\Users>ECHO %teste%
000020

C:\Users>SET /A teste+=1
17
```

where `00020` in octal is `16` in decimal.

Comment: Hey Ebbe thanks for answering! Clear enought, but.. i'm curious, can you explain to me wy they needed to deal with octal numbers in bash ? I would never tought about it until you said.. it's that really important ? I mean, can you really program something more usefull than using other numbers conversions like decimals ? Best Regards!

Comment: Well it's an old convention i guess. It's also used in many languages like C, Perl, Ruby etc. Hex is also supported, where something like  0x10 is interpreted as 16

Comment: +1. Ooh, nice catch! I knew this at one time, but had apparently forgotten. Thanks for the refresher. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The number `8` doesn't have 5 leading zeros. If you're doing math, use real numbers. :-)

This works fine on my machine in a command window in Win7 64-bit:

```
C:\Users\Ken>set /a teste=8
8
C:\Users\Ken>set /a teste+=1
9
C:\Users\Ken>set /a teste+=1
10
C:\Users\Ken>echo %test3%
10

C:\Users\Ken>
```

Comment: number 7 doesn't have 5 leading zeros too.. but still works with the operator!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by removing leadig zeros:

```
C:\>set teste=000008

C:\>echo %teste%
000008

C:\>for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %i in ("$0%teste%") do @set teste=%j

C:\>set /a teste+=1
9
```

Comment: Yes, but the right answer was given already (octal numbers) so I'l like to show, how to avoid that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The leading zeros makes things complicated; I would have expected the '000007' not to have worked in that way - the bottom line is: the '000008'; or any '8' with leading zeros is being handled as a string. Example:

C:\Users\op>set f=foo

C:\Users\op>echo %f%

foo

C:\Users\op>set /a f+=1

1

Answer (score 0):

In response to

```
"number 7 doesn't have 5 leading zeros too.. but still works with the operator!"
```

You will only have trouble with the leading zeros for numbers > 7 because 0-7 Octal are the same as 0-7 Decimal!